# Finding the last two digits before the decimal point for the number (4+sqrt(11))^n

Tags: java, performance, precision, bigdecimal

I am doing a problem in which I have to find the last two digits before the decimal point for the number 
**[4 + sqrt(11)]<sup>n</sup>**.

For example, when  **n = 4, [4 + sqrt(11)]<sup>4</sup> = 2865.78190...** the answer is 65. Where n can vary from 2 <= n <= 10<sup>9</sup>.

My solution - I have tried to build a square root function which calculate the sqrt of 11
which a precision equal to value of n input by the user.

I have used `BigDecimal` in Java to avoid overflow problems.

```
public class MathGenius {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        long a = 0;
        try {
            a = reader.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a integer value");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Setting precision for square root 0f 11. str contain string like 0.00001
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("0.");
        for (long i = 1; i <= a; i++)
            str.append('0');
        str.append('1');

        // Calculating square root of 11 having precision equal to number enter
        // by the user.
        BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("11"), precision = new BigDecimal(
                str.toString()), guess = num.divide(new BigDecimal("2")), change = num
                .divide(new BigDecimal("4"));
        BigDecimal TWO = new BigDecimal("2.0");
        BigDecimal MinusOne = new BigDecimal("-1"), temp = guess
                .multiply(guess);
        while ((((temp).subtract(num)).compareTo(precision) > 0)
                || num.subtract(temp).compareTo(precision) > 0) {

            guess = guess.add(((temp).compareTo(num) > 0) ? change
                    .multiply(MinusOne) : change);

            change = change.divide(TWO);
            temp = guess.multiply(guess);
        }

        // Calculating the (4+sqrt(11))^n
        BigDecimal deci = BigDecimal.ONE;
        BigDecimal num1 = guess.add(new BigDecimal("4.0"));
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
             deci = deci.multiply(num1);

        // Calculating two digits before the decimal point
        StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer(deci.toPlainString());
        int index = 0;
        while (str1.charAt(index) != '.')
            index++;
        // Printing output

        System.out.print(str1.charAt(index - 2));
        System.out.println(str1.charAt(index - 1));
    }
}
```

This solution works up to n = 200, but then it begins to slow down. It stops working for n = 1000.

What is a good method to deal with problem?

```
2 -- 53
3 -- 91
4    65
5    67
6    13
7    71
8    05
9    87
10   73
11   51
12   45
13   07
14   33
15   31
16   85
17   27
18   93
19   11
20   25
21   47
22   53
23   91
24   65
25   67
```

Comment: I would look for a pattern in those first 200... then maybe do an inductive proof to say that there really is a pattern; then use that instead of calculating this.

Comment: @d'alar'cop - can u explain which pattern ???

Comment: Can you post the first 20 or so of the results? - I mean just those 2 digits you are looking for

Comment: Have you tried instead of multiplying 1 by 1, do something like find the solution for n = 500 and then multiply that solution with itself to get the solution for n = 1000? You could obviously find the solution for n = 500 using 2 solutions for n = 250, etc...

Comment: Why use all digits to multiply. In for loop multiply successive (4+sqrt(11)) but use only 2 digits before decimal and the fraction part in each iteration

Comment: Yeah, Tejas is right, because you are doing it a loop like that (instead of using pow()) you could chop all the front off leaving the last 2 digits and fraction. That should run ok.

Comment: ok  Tejas i will go for that

Comment: ALSO, there is a pretty damn obvious pattern in there... from n=22 it's starting from n=2 again... check if that's consistent. Then just keep those nums in an array... then base your result on the provided n with appropriate %ing.

Comment: there is a pattern repeating at n=22  @d'alar'cop

Comment: @d'alar'cop you give the idea for getting answer thanks!!!

Comment: @T.J. No worries. Excellent. Tick the answer if it resolved the problem :)

Comment: it does **not** repeat after 22 http://ideone.com/TA0Re6

Comment: @JigarJoshi Interesting; that uses a different implementation... I guess this maybe indicates a need to change the code altogether

Comment: @JigarJoshi you are doing it with with less precision that's why getting wrong answers.Increase the precesion when n tends to 20 otherwise error begins to build up .

Comment: @T.J increased scale to 15, still don't see the pattern http://ideone.com/TA0Re6

Comment: @JigarJoshi  for n=19     4+sqrt(11) gives 7.31662479035539984911423634368187601806354791733610909432172775268554687511   and value is 26418301962683911.999230244819156...........

Comment: @JigarJoshi rounding error has begin to show up at n= 19 in your case set it at some higher precision

Comment: Hey TJ, look in the comments for my answer - someone posted the proof that there is a pattern.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687736/does-lfloor4-sqrt11n-rfloor-pmod-100-repeat-every-20-cycles-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At n=22 the results seem to repeat from the position of n=2. 
So keep those 20 values in an array in the same order as in your list e.g. `nums[20]`.

Then when the user provides an n:

```
return nums[(n-2)%20]
```

There is now a proof of this pattern repeating [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687736/does-lfloor4-sqrt11n-rfloor-pmod-100-repeat-every-20-cycles-of).

Alternatively, if you insist on computing at length; since you calculating the power by looping multiplication (and not BigDecimal pow(n)) you could trim the number you are working with at the front to the last 2 digits and the fractional part.

Comment: @JigarJoshi No. I'd want to do some more tests and maybe a proof. But I did say "seems" and I also showed an alternative solution just in case. However, in the question comments, OP says that there is indeed a pattern - I'm not sure how he verified this.

Comment: Nathaniel Johnston posted a proof at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158420/

Comment: @NoahSnyder Thank you, sir. Very nicely done by Nathaniel. It's nice to see the proof!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler solution for you...

Use the rational representation of `4+sqrt(11)`:

```
BigInteger hundred     = new BigInteger("100");
BigInteger numerator   = new BigInteger("5017987099799880733320738241");
BigInteger denominator = new BigInteger("685833597263928519195691392");
BigInteger result = numerator.pow(n).divide(denominator.pow(n)).mod(hundred);
```

**UPDATE:**

As you've mentioned in the comments below, this procedure is prone to precision-loss, and will eventually yield an incorrect result. I found this question to be rather interesting on the mathematical aspect, and so I published a question on MO (https://mathoverflow.net/q/158420/27456).

You can read the answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/158422/27456.

Comment: 4+sqrt(11) is irrational .. after some time round off error will be significant

Comment: @T.J, but that is true regardless of anything you do on any Turing machine (i.e. any modern computer)!!!!! Your calculation will eventually take place with a rational number, whether you use the numerator/denominator above, or any other function which calculates the square root of 11.

Comment: but i need to calculate the exact value ..Question was to actually look for pattern in it ... ronding error will make answers differ from one another. Twist is not to calculate but to find pattern.

Comment: @T.J: For `double val = 4+sqrt(11)`, the numerator/denominator above are 100% accurate, with no loss of precision. Of course, the precision-loss itself occurs when you use `sqrt`, but you cannot avoid this (unless you implement a `BigRational` class, which calculates the square root to a more accurate level then provided by the `double` type). My suggestion is merely a simpler and more accurate method for tackling the problem described at your question. If you're looking for the actual pattern, then that's a different issue.